# Custom connections between layers Keras

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

I would like to manually define connections in neural network between layers using TensorFlow and keras with Python. By default connections are beween all pairs of neurons. I need to make connections as in picture below.[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, to join two output layers into the next layer input, use the following design:

```
out1 = keras.layers.YourLayer1(**params**)
out2 = keras.layers.YourLayer2(**params**)
NextLayer = keras.layers.YourLayer3(**params**)[out1, out2]
```

[image]